# Advice on using Wordpress or a PHP Framework?

Tags: php, security, wordpress, frameworks, kohana

I am currently building a blog type website for myself. I have used wordpress in the past and really enjoy it, but when it comes to building more than just a blog I usually get bogged down in writing hacks for it.

The site I'm building is going to pretty much be a blog, but with a 'question and answer' side to it (NOT A FORUM - purely Q&A). Therefore, bbPress and buddyPress doesn't quite hit the mark. I have used CI for awhile now, but when it comes to security I fall short. CI does not have an auth library, however, Kohana does.

My question is: I would like to have full control over my site, but I'm worried about my lack of knowledge in the security department. Would I be better off using Wordpress as a base, or would it be beneficial for me in the long run to use something like Kohana?

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would like to say that you can't compare Wordpress and Kohana. One is a content management system and the other is a programming framework.

As for your question: Since you've stated you're not that experienced with security I suggest you stick with Wordpress; It's maintained by developers who know what they're doing.

If you want to go ahead and create something yourself then make sure you keep up-to date with all the current security issues and how to resolve them. Here are a few resources you might be interested in: [PHPSEC](http://phpsec.org/), [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [PHP Security](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php). You should probably read those anyway (as you're writing Wordpress plugins).

Good luck with your choice either way.

Comment: my question does really boil down to security, i am semi-advanced at programing php, but i often fear that i lack in the security department. However, i have noticed that kohana has a built in auth library and i wonder if i used it to the fullest would it provide me good security?

Comment: There's more to security than the Auth library. You're a semi-advanced PHP programmer, why don't you look at the source code and evaluate it for yourself?

Comment: I'll look into it! thanks for you help pixel, i'll probably stick with wordpress for now and build my own on the side.

Comment: One of the best reasons for using a massively implemented foundation like WordPress is precisely to avoid dealing with security issues - if anyone has seen it already, they have.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you can write the "hacks" for wordpress, than modify it to your needs.

If you think you can write the security better, than use Zend Framework since it has a Auth lib.
http://framework.zend.com/

I dont realy know about kohana

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... for the Questions and Answers, have a look at [Qhub](http://qhub.com/). I'm aboutto implement it for a client of mine who's an adoption counselor. She gets tons of questions via emails and it's always the same ones over and over. I saw it on Design Reviver a while back and I thought it was a great idea. Plus I got in contact with one of the co-founders of Qhub and they told me that they are implementing some more privacy and privileges controls which is really good news since I only want my client to be able to answer the questions.

I would use WP with Qhub to be honest. If it's a blog-type site and you're already comfortable with WP, why not stick with it?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TDO Mini Forms plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/). I think it may serve your needs perfectly!